# C++ Two Versions of the Same Executable

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cmake, makefile

I built a c++ executable (e.g. `process_file`) from source on my system. I have the executables in a build directory, from which I can use them (e.g. `home/siet/build/process_file file.txt`).

However, in my system there is already an executable with the same name (e.g. `process_file` command works from any directory), which does something different.

How can I link the invocation of the executable to my new build? (i.e. `process_file` should call the executable in `home/siet/build/`)

Comment: Are you asking how you can adjust your `PATH` or something else?

Answer (score 2):

In your shell, use an alias or function, or modify your PATH.  For example, in `$HOME/.profile`, you might have

```
alias process_file=home/siet/build/process_file
```

or

```
PATH=home/siet/build/process_file:$PATH
```

The advantage of the alias (or function) is that it can be bypassed

```
$ \process_file
```

causes the shell to search the PATH, and does not invoke the alias.